# Chef: Cookbook can't depend on older version of other cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, versioning, cookbook

## Background

*Note: Keep in mind for this whole problem that I want to use version `0.0.3` of the `environment-cookbook`.*

*Note 2: We NEVER had this problem before. This is recent and we don't know what caused it.*

### 1. `environment-cookbook` and `environment-cookbook-machines`

To build domains, we have two cookbooks:

- one for *provisioning machines*: `environment-cookbook-machines`
- one for *domain configuration*: `environment-cookbook`

When I check the Chef-server:

```
$ knife cookbook list -a | grep environment
environment-cookbook 0.0.3 0.0.4 0.0.5 0.0.6 0.0.7
```

Looking at `company-environment-cookbook 0.0.3`'s `metadata.json`, I see it depends on `dir-library 0.13.6`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "dir-library": "= 0.13.6"
}
```

Whereas `environment-cookbook 0.0.4` **and higher** depend on `dir-library 0.13.7`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "dir-library": "=0.13.7"
}
```

### 2. `wrapper-domain` and `wrapper-domain-machines`

As each domain can depend on a specific version of `environment-cookbook`, we use wrapper cookbooks for each domain, respectively

- `wrapper-domain-machines`
- `wrapper-domain`

Checking `metadata.json` for both of the wrappers shows a dependency on `environment-cookbook 0.0.3` (this is the version I want):

```
"dependencies": {
  "environment-cookbook": "= 0.0.3"
  ...
}
```

`wrapper-domain-machines` also shows a dependency on `environment-cookbook-machines 0.0.3`.

The `Berksfile.lock` for those wrapper cookbooks look like this:

```
GRAPH 
environment-cookbook (0.0.3)
    dir-library (= 0.13.6)
environment-cookbook-machines (0.0.3)  # Only here for wrapper-cookbook-machines
    dir-library (= 0.13.6)
```

### 3. Dependency graph

When I run `berks wiz` on my `wrapper-domain-machines` cookbook, I get the following dependency graph:
[image]

***SO EVERYTHING SEEMS FINE.***

## Problem

When I run the domain build through a CI Job on Hudson, I see the following at the beginning of the log file:

```
INFO: Using dir-library (0.13.6)
INFO: Using environment-cookbook (0.0.3)
INFO: Using environment-cookbook-machines (0.0.3)
INFO: Installing environment-cookbook (0.0.3) from chef-server-url
INFO: Using dir-library (0.13.6)
```

A little bit further:

```
INFO: Run List is [recipe[wrapper-domain-machines::up-machines]]
INFO: Run List expands to [wrapper-domain-machines::up-machines]
INFO: Loading cookbooks [wrapper-domain-machines@0.0.2, dir-library@0.13.6, environment-cookbook-machines@0.0.3]
```

**So far so good.** It's using version `0.0.3` for `environment-cookbook` and `0.13.6` for `dir-library`.

**Later on during the build:**

```
INFO: Run List is [recipe[environment-cookbook::prepare_machine]]
INFO: Run List expands to [environment-cookbook::prepare_machine]
INFO: Starting Chef Run for domain.company.com
INFO: Running start handlers
INFO: Start handlers complete.
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["environment-cookbook::prepare_machine"][0m
INFO: Loading cookbooks [environment-cookbook@0.0.7, dir-library@0.13.7]
```

**STOP, WHAT ?**

***INFO: Loading cookbooks [environment-cookbook@0.0.7, dir-library@0.13.7]***

## What we tried so far

1. Delete cached cookbooks

   - Delete the cookbooks from `.berkshelf/cookbooks`
   - Re-run the build (downloads automatically from chef-server)
   - Still picks up `0.0.8`
2. Check for dependencies on `environment-cookbook` in other cookbooks: **NONE**.
3. Delete and re-install all versions of `environment-cookbook` from `0.0.3` to `0.0.7`: no luck.
4. Clean chef clients and nodes before re-running: no luck either.

## Questions

- Why is it changing to the latest version of `environment-cookbook (0.0.7)`, thus picking it's dependency `dir-library (0.13.7)` ?
- How can I troubleshoot this ?
- How to avoid this in the future ?

This is really a show-stopper for us.

Ask me any further clarifications and I'll update this post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I would find a `node.run_list <whatever>` call within your recipes somewhere, changing the runlist (I'll guess changing the wrapper cookbook used). Side question: Which chef version do you use (as client and server) Open source chef server < 11.1 had a dependency resolution bug which cause the resolver to hang and never return, but anyway it always cause a run stop if there's unsatified constraints, so I can only tink of one of  your recipes messing with the runlist at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is the same problem with chef we ran into. It boils down *run-time* revision control, as opposed to *compile time* revision control.

Lesson learned: Unconstrained cookbook versions at run-time are dangerous when running chef at scale.

## Background

You're using Berkshelf to manage your cookbook dependencies, that's great and will ensure the correct versions get loaded into the chef server. The subtle problem is that each cookbook has its own dependency tree. At run-time, when you add multiple cookbooks to a node's run-list, chef server must calculate a fresh tree of dependencies. The problem can appear random because it depends on the combination of cookbooks you have on the run list. The more cookbooks, the more potential for conflict.

We tried to fix this problem by explicitly setting dependencies our cookbook metadata files. What we discovered was that Chef would silently fail to resolve the dependency tree for some of our cookbooks and default back to an older version for which it would calculate dependencies. Very puzzling.

We got closer to the problem when we began to explicitly set the version of the cookbook on the run-list. We began to get error messages that chef was unable to resolve dependencies. What was especially weird was that this problem impacted our production chef server the most. We eventually determined that it was because on production we had all historical versions of our cookbooks loaded. Purging old cookbooks helped, but did not solve our problems.

Chef had worked fine for nearly two years before we discovered these problems. It was time and scale that exposed a fatal flaw in our system. At run-time you need to fix the versions of your cookbooks to match the configurations you have previously tested.

## Analysis

Coming from a Java background I equated the problem to how we we can run multiple applications on a tomcat server.

Maven is the build tool that manages each apps dependencies and creates a package for upload into tomcat. In Chef it is Berkshelf that fufils this function.

The big difference is at run-time. Tomcat creates a separate classpath for the jars belong to each application. This provides strong isolation between applications at run-time, safely allowing them to run different versions of the same cookbook. This was the impossible problem faced by Chef, at runtime chef-client only runs a single set of cookbooks.

## Solutions

While I'm not a fan of policy files I present them as the option favoured by Chef.

### Policy files

While most users are oblivious to the problem being solved, chef have developed a new feature called policy files:

- https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_policyfile.html
- https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/08/18/policyfiles-a-guided-tour/
- https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/10/05/policyfiles-why-what-and-how/

In a nutshell what they're doing is setting a nodes run-list in advance, at compile time.

One big benefit of policy files is that they result in a faster chef run. The chef server no longer has to figure out the large dependency tree, this can be a big saving in chef installations with large numbers of cookbooks.

### Environment cookbook pattern

Personally I'm not a fan of policy files, because I had already discovered the Environment cookbook pattern, a poorly understood but powerful feature of chef that already existed:

- http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/

Now every time I deploy cookbooks I always use a Chef environment. The natural way to provide isolation in chef (Did I point out it was poorly understood). Here's an example using berkshelf:

```
berks upload 
berks apply my_app_cookbook_version1
```

The very handy "apply" command will use the Berkshelf lock file to update the cookbook versions in the environment "my_app_cookbook_version1". Now you've fixed the run-time to match your tested conditions.

The consequence of course is that I have an environment per application cookbook:

- my_app_cookbook_version1
- my_app_cookbook_version2
- etc

This is actually a bonus for me, because it enables me to bootstrap infrastructure against something I've already tested:

```
knife bootstrap --environment my_app_cookbook_version1 ...
```

It creates predictability and means loading new cookbooks is not going to magically change my servers in production.

A bonus is that environments provide a record of the cookbook versions in use and a convenient place to set override attributes associated with deployment, like "app_owner", "app_version", etc.

Apologies for the long posting.